# How can I round up the price in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I'd like to know if there is a way to **round up** the prices in WooCommerce keeping 2 decimals displayed (so the price will end with the first and second decimal ,00).

For example: €12,54 will be rounded to €13,00 and €145,67 will be rounded up to €146,00.

I'm using a plugin to discount the product price i.e. €39,00 - 20% = €35,10 (it should became €36,00).

I'd like to round up all the prices as explained before.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You can't really round up **globally all real** calculated prices, like taxes, shipping, discounts, totals and others third party plugins calculated prices. Rounding calculated prices requires to be done case by case…

You can only **round up globally all "displayed" formatted prices** keeping the 2 decimals. For that there are 2 steps explained below:

**1) The following hooked function will round the raw displayed prices in WooCommerce:**

It will return the next highest integer value by rounding up that value if necessary.

```
add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', 'round_up_raw_woocommerce_price' )
function round_up_raw_woocommerce_price( $price ){
    return ceil( $price );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

> Note that All Woocommerce price formatting functions will use our rounded prices from our first hooked function…

**2) Formatting displayed prices in WooCommerce.**

WooCommerce uses [the function `wc_price()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_price.html#534-598) everywhere to format prices as defined in the WooCommerce settings.

So if you need to format any raw price you will use that formatting function like in this example:

```
// Get the WC_Product Object instance from the product ID
$product = wc_get_product ( $product_id );

// Get the product active price for display
$price_to_display = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );

// Format the product active price
$price_html = wc_price( $price_to_display );

// Output
echo $price_html
```

Or the same thing, more compact using `WC_Product` built in method `get_price_html()`:

```
// Get the WC_Product Object instance from the product ID
$product = wc_get_product ( $product_id );

// Display the formatted product price
echo $product->get_price_html();
```

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, thank you so much for your answer. I've tried to add the first part of the code:

add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', 'round_up_raw_woocommerce_price' )
function round_up_raw_woocommerce_price( $price ){
    return ceil( $price );
}

But I had issue and the website crashed. I've put attention that in the end of the functions.php file there was not the ?>. However I think the problem was caused by the position where I put the code. 

There are 2 "if" functions in the end of the file and I think the code should be put before these 2 sections.